# ASP.NET MVC ContentPlaceHolder overriding hard-coded content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, contentplaceholder

This is what I have in the aspx page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Website - <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" /></title>
</head>
```

This is what's in the view:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    Homepage
</asp:Content>
```

For some reason, this HTML is generated:

```
<title>Homepage</title>
```

The 'Website - ' part is getting removed. Anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phil Haack has an explanation of this issue (and a work-around) at http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/03/tipjar-title-tags-and-master-pages.aspx .  The work-around is that you use an asp:LiteralControl for the static part of your page title.

Answer (score 0):

could you do something like this?

```
<head runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"><title>Website</title></asp:ContentPlaceHolder >
</head>
```

and then override the whole title string in your view?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I could, but what I'd like to do is set the first part just once. Let's say in the future, I want to change the title from 'Website - Homepage' to 'New Website - Homepage'. Instead of changing it in every view, all I'd have to do is modify the master page.